# Creating custom JS syntax / shorthand

Tags: javascript

I would like to create some custom JS syntax. Is there a way I can write a method so that the following would work:

```
var someDict = {"abc": 1, "efg": 2}
someDict.keys
someDict.values
```

instead of:

```
Object.keys(someDict)
Object.values(someDict)
```

In Swift this sort of thing can be done via extensions, I'm just wondering if there's a way in JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an object with getters:

```js
class ObjWithKeyValGetters {
  constructor(obj) {
    Object.assign(this, obj);
  }
  get keys() {
    return Object.keys(this);
  }
  get values() {
    return Object.values(this);
  }
}
const myObj = new ObjWithKeyValGetters({"abc": 1, "efg": 2});
console.log(myObj.keys);
console.log(myObj.values);
```

Comment: Awesome thanks! So basically I just create a custom class for this sort of thing. There isn't a way to extend the existing object class?

Comment: You *can* mutate the built-in object prototypes, but that's very bad practice - that sort of thing is what got us debacles like [this one](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-flatMap/pull/56).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for prototype . you can add new `methods` to `Object` with `prototype` like :

```
var current = Object.prototype.valueOf;

// Since my property "-prop-value" is cross-cutting and isn't always
// on the same prototype chain, I want to modify Object.prototype: 
Object.prototype.valueOf = function() {
  if (this.hasOwnProperty('-prop-value')) {
    return this['-prop-value'];
  } else {
    // It doesn't look like one of my objects, so let's fall back on 
    // the default behavior by reproducing the current behavior as best we can.
    // The apply behaves like "super" in some other languages.
    // Even though valueOf() doesn't take arguments, some other hook may.
    return current.apply(this, arguments);
  }
}
```

as modified [`MDN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) pollyfill for `Object.keys`:

```
Object.prototype.pollufillKeys = (function() {
    'use strict';
    var hasOwnProperty = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty,
        hasDontEnumBug = !({
            toString: null
        }).propertyIsEnumerable('toString'),
        dontEnums = [
            'toString',
            'toLocaleString',
            'valueOf',
            'hasOwnProperty',
            'isPrototypeOf',
            'propertyIsEnumerable',
            'constructor'
        ],
        dontEnumsLength = dontEnums.length;

    return function(obj) {
        if (typeof obj !== 'function' && (typeof obj !== 'object' || obj === null)) {
            throw new TypeError('Object.keys called on non-object');
        }

        var result = [],
            prop, i;

        for (prop in obj) {
            if (hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop)) {
                result.push(prop);
            }
        }

        if (hasDontEnumBug) {
            for (i = 0; i < dontEnumsLength; i++) {
                if (hasOwnProperty.call(obj, dontEnums[i])) {
                    result.push(dontEnums[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    };
}());
```